# Unique Constraint based on Checkbox

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add constraint only on certain record, those with certain checkbox is true

```
Name              Checkbox
-----            ----------
Tom                  N
Adam                 N
Brad                 Y
Ali                  N
Wissam               Y
```

so, in the sample table above, oracle must prevent creating records with names (Brad, Wissam)
and allow the rest
appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a primary key on the table, you can use:

```
create unique index unq_t_name_y on <table_name>
     ( (case when checkbox = 'Y' then name end),
       (case when checkbox = 'N' then <primary key> end)
     )
```

Comment: You can actually remove the case for `checkbox = 'N'`. Oracle won't index rows where all columns of the index are NULL. If you just have a single column (expression), then the corresponding row won't be indexed if that expression is null.

Comment: @Gordon thank you for your help. you're only missing the table name. also, as the above commenter noted, I don't need the case for `checkbox='N'`.